# dropoff element type using parameters

Tags: anylogic

I have a sub process in my model and there is a drop-off block inside that ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcBNu.png)). I want the drop-off element type could be set in model. I mean that I want to use this sub process in every part of model with different element types. so I used a parameter and set its type as an Agent and its control type is Agent Creator ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mml7p.png)). but the problem is that in the drop-off element type field I cant use that because that parameter is unknown in that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you described is called 'parametrised Agent'. This can be achieved by ticking `Parametrized type` checkbox in the *Advanced Java* area of the Agent's properties see screenshot below.

In the example pictured the parametrised type is called `T`. This then has to be set into the *Element Type* field of the **Dropoff** component. For more info please see [Agent help](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/agent.html)  and [generic parameters help](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/data/generic-parameters.html).

[image: screenshot].